# White space is coming on top of my activity Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using fragments in my activity and loading web view inside a fragment. For login I am using oauth2 and opening URL in web view in a dialog fragment on top of previous fragment. After successful signing when I am coming back to previous activity and closing the dialog and moving user to next screen unnecessary white space is coming on the top of the screen.
If I am not opening that dialog fragment than that white space is not coming and its working fine.

This is my login dialog layout code :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivClose"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/zm_ic_close"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[In this image app is leaving space at the top of screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuLZ.png)

Comment: Can you share your full code. and Your base activity code